# Java -> MySQL query issue

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a java query to insert to MySQl but i keep getting errors.  please see the code below. PS the connection to the DB is fine.

here is the query that is being called

```
public  String newEmpInsert() {
    return newEmpInsert;
}

private String newEmpInsert = "INSERT INTO empInfo"
    + "(firstName, lastName, SSN, address, salary, pin, empLevel, contactInfo) "
    + "VALUES ("+firstName+", "+lastName+", "+SSN+", "+address+", "+salary+",  "+pin+","+empLevel+", "+contactInfo+")";
```

here is the handler that is being called from the main

```
    public void newEmpInsert() {

    // SQL Connection
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = MySQL_connection_test.getConnection();
        // Create a statement
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery(queries.newEmpInsert());

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("--------->>Invalid query!!!!<<--------------");
        System.out.println("Your query has an error, please try again!!");
    }

    // Close the connection
    finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Database closed");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Database closed");
    }
}
```

every time i run a query i am getting the invalid query catch.  the variables are being set properly within the class and everything.

Comment: Look at the exception. Try adding `System.out.printnl(e.getMesasge())`. The exceptions almost always include ***very*** relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Please change third row as VALUES and try to wrap your string values with single quotes.

```
private String newEmpInsert = "INSERT INTO empInfo"
+ "(firstName, lastName, SSN, address, salary, pin, empLevel, contactInfo) "
+ " VALUES ("+firstName+", "+lastName+", "+SSN+", "+address+", "+salary+", "+pin+", 
+ "+empLevel+", "+contactInfo+")";
```

Comment: No, that's not the case. The string literals were not wrapped with single quotes. But that's not the preferred way as it is vulnerable with sql injection. Parameterizing the values would be the best idea.

Comment: i had the string literals wrapped in single quotes as well at first just to try different things but that didnt have any effect on the result

Comment: Did you try by changing as VALUES

Comment: For MySQL, VALUE and VALUES are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here cause you build wrong sql statement. As i look on your code you missing single quote on text field. Also your approach build Statement not good, it is easy get failure with special character like ' or " and expose for sql inject attach. Try using prepare statement and bind parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `+` from the quoted string at the end of the third line and the beginning of the fourth line:

```
private String newEmpInsert = "INSERT INTO empInfo"
+ "(firstName, lastName, SSN, address, salary, pin, empLevel, contactInfo) "
+ "VALUE ("+firstName+", "+lastName+", "+SSN+", "+address+", "+salary+", "+pin+", "
    // added close quote at the end of the above line
+empLevel+", "+contactInfo+")";
    // plus sign and quote deleted at beginning of above line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String newEmpInsert = "INSERT INTO empInfo"
    + "(firstName, lastName, SSN, address, salary, pin, empLevel, contactInfo) "
    + "VALUES ("+firstName+", "+lastName+", "+SSN+", "+address+", "+salary+",  
"+pin+","+empLevel+", "+contactInfo")";
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as [this one by Anura Adhikari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23258540), but with less explanation.